# File Monitoring using watchdog library

Tags: python

I have written one python script to monitor one local folder which is having only .txt files and i want to start this script automatically if some changes happened to the folder(created,deleted or updated)

I tried to run this script and also tried to make changes in the directory, but i couldn't see any output and no error messages. It always says "Process finished with exit code 0" can any one review my code and give me some tips where to correct to get the expected out put.

```
import os
import sys
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

#Step 1 Create the event handler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    patterns = ".txt"
    ignore_patterns = None
    ignore_directories = False
    case_sensitive = True
    event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_patterns, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)

    #step 2 Handle all the events

    def on_created(event):
        print("new files has been created!")

    def on_deleted(event):
        print("Some files has been Deleted")

    def on_modified(event):
        print("Some files has been modified")

    def on_moved(event):
        print("Some files has been moved")

        #step 3 specify to the handler that we want these functions to be called

        event_handler.on_created = on_created
        event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
        event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
        event_handler.on_moved = on_moved

        #step 4 create an observer

        path = "T:\Laboratory\Instruments\Worklists\TrackMateRacks\old"
        go_recursively = True
        my_observer = Observer()
        my_observer.path(event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)

        # start the observer

        my_observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            my_observer.stop()
        my_observer.join()
```

Comment: You didn't execute any of the functions. You need to at least call `on_moved()`.

Comment: nothinf is executed after calling the function  om_moved

Comment: Ah now i noticed - you indent all the lines wrong. You have to un-indent everything after `#step 3 specify to the handler that we want these functions to be called`.

Comment: ok i will try this. other than that can you see any mistake in the script?

Answer (score 0):

you have to move the lines after " # start the observer" to the very left.
otherwise there will be executed nothing. that lines are part of on_moved(). but you want them to be executed if you start the script.

or

for most programs it's useful to add this line:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

bevore line "# start the observer"

than your my_observer.start() will be executed, if you call your script. but if you import your script in another script, this will not be executed, but the other script can use all the functions, you created.

Comment: I made all those changes and still it is not executing

Comment: now i am having this error "AttributeError: 'WindowsApiObserver' object has no attribute 'path'"

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you're really new to Python. You've to watch the indents, they're part of the syntax.

Exceptionally I reformat the complete code for you:

```
import os
import sys
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

#Step 1 Create the event handler

patterns = ".txt"
ignore_patterns = None
ignore_directories = False
case_sensitive = True
event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_patterns, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)

#step 2 Handle all the events

def on_created(event):
    print("new files has been created!")

def on_deleted(event):
    print("Some files has been Deleted")

def on_modified(event):
    print("Some files has been modified")

def on_moved(event):
    print("Some files has been moved")

    #step 3 specify to the handler that we want these functions to be called

    event_handler.on_created = on_created
    event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
    event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
    event_handler.on_moved = on_moved

#step 4 create an observer
def main():
    path = "T:\Laboratory\Instruments\Worklists\TrackMateRacks\old"
    go_recursively = True
    my_observer = Observer()
    my_observer.path(event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)

    # start the observer

    my_observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_observer.stop()
    my_observer.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()

#end of file
```

Good luck!